# Implicit conversion in C# without creating new object

Tags: c#, casting, implicit-conversion

I'm trying to implement some implicit cast for an object. Currently I'm doing this:

```
public class PathSelector 
{
    private string _path = null;
    public string Path
    {
        get { return _path; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _path)
            {
                _path = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Path");
            }
        }
    }

    static public implicit operator string(PathSelector pathSelector)
    {
        return pathSelector.Path;
    }

    static public implicit operator PathSelector(string path)
    {
        return new PathSelector() { Path = path };
    }
}
```

As you can see in the cast from `String`to `PathSelector` I'm generating a new `PathSelector` object.

I use it like this:

```
public PathSelector PluginPathSelector { get; set; } = new PathSelector();
public string PluginPath
{
    get
    {
        return PluginPathSelector;
    }

    set
    {
        PluginPathSelector = value;
    }
}
```

What I don't like about this solution is, that I always create a new object when I assign a string to a `PathSelector` object. This also means, that in the `PathSelector` property a `set` section is needed. I would like to assign the `string` to the object, that is already created. Is there a way to implement this?

Comment: Well there are many benefits to immutability (a.k.a creating a new object each time!) Due to the static nature of the method, there is no instance to grab - the point being that you can use the method at any point. You should create a method on your object to merge the two together.

Comment: How about upon setting PluginPath, set the PluginPathSelector.Path property instead (same with getting it), I see no reason to go for implicit conversions here. I actually only see problems with the code as is, seeing that the PathSelector is an class implementing INotifyPropertyChanged (and you check actually it's Path's equality in the setter)

Comment: @Icepickle thats what I did. But I wanted to implement the implicit cast to make the object usage more convenient in binding scenarios

Comment: Set section is not needed - you can pass path in constructor instead. Then you will have nice immutable object.

Comment: @Evk A `set`section will still be needed, since a new object is assigned to the reference

Comment: Probably you mean some other set section. I mean one in `Path` property.

Comment: Why not simply make the backing field a string as well?

Comment: @Evk ah ok. I meant the one in this part `public PathSelector PluginPathSelector { get; set; } = new PathSelector();`. Thats the one I want to get rid of. For the Path property it is needed for binding purposes (Thats why there is the `OnPropertyChanged` call, which I missed to remove)

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen It is a string

Comment: Well then just remove those operators, remove setter and work with PluginPathSelector.Path directly.

Comment: Ok, we're running in circles ;-). I just wanted to know if there is a way to alter the object, that the implicit cast is used on. It seems there is non

Comment: You can change the path like this: `PluginPathSelector.Path = value;`, is that what you want?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen No, I wanted to do that in the static implicit operator

Comment: That can't be done because that is a **conversion** operator, it does not have access to the variable (or whatever) the converted object will be placed into.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Ok, thanks. Thats the answer I was searching for (at least I know it is not possible). Post it as an answer and I'll accept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally understood what you wanted to do.

You wanted this:

```
x.PluginPathSelector = "some string";
```

To directly change the Path property of the existing object inside `x.PluginPathSelector`, instead of constructing a new `PathSelector` instance and assigning to `x.PluginPathSelector`.

In other words, you want this:

```
x.PluginPathSelector = "some string";
```

to be silently handled as though you wrote:

```
x.PluginPathSelector.Path = "some string";
```

But from within the static conversion operator:

```
static public implicit operator PathSelector(string path)
```

And **no**, this cannot be done, because this is a **conversion** operator.

This statement:

```
x.PluginPathSelector = "some string";
```

is handled this way:

1. First convert `"some string"` into a `PathSelector` (through the conversion operator)
2. Assign the new object to the property

The conversion operator implementation have no way to reach or know about the target of the object it returns, be it a property or a variable or whatever.

So no. This cannot be done.

You will have to manually do the change yourself if you want to avoid constructing new instances all the time.

```
x.PluginPathSelector.Path = "some string";
```

Comment: Hint, you could make `PathSelector` an immutable struct, then you don't create *instances* as such.

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completeness and as a hacking way, you can handle that by using the ugly way of:

- inheriting the class that contains PathSelector property from DynamicClass
- override the TrySetMember function
- handle the conversion and setting the Path property in that function